# Trying to mock a TwitterAPI Client in Rails with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rspec, mocking, stub

I have a little function to get some tweets, I just want to add some simple tests too:

```
def get_tweets_in_time_range(search, since_time, until_time)
    client = TwitterAPI.new.client

    begin
        return client.search(
            search,
            include_entities: true,
            result_type: "recent",
            since: since_time.to_date, 
            until: until_time.to_date
        )
    rescue Twitter::Error::Unauthorized
        dispatch_error "Unauthorized credentials"
        return []
    end
end
```

So I have started writing a test that looks like this:

```
it "should return tweets when successful" do 
    allow_any_instance_of(TwitterAPI::Client).to receive(:search).with(@search, @since_time, @until_time).and_return(unprocessed_tweets(3, @tag_name, @now-1.weeks, @now))
end
```

When I run this I get the error:

> NameError:
>   uninitialized constant TwitterAPI::Client

Whats the correct way of going about this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: "TwitterApi" -> "TwitterAPI" (caps)

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom will post edit question, with this change.

Comment: @NNNNNNNNNNDelicious have you the NameError again after the fix?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ That is correct. I fixed the error mentioned above and posted the new error in the edit.